# How to pass a 2 Dimensional array as an argument of function in C?

Tags: arrays, function, pointers

### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* input(char* arr,int N, int M){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]); 
        }   
    }
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    int i,N,M;    
    scanf("%d%d",&N,&M);
    char arr[N][M];
    arr=input(arr,N,M);
    return 0;
}
```

### Explanation:

**The above given is a simple program where the user inputs the data into a 2-D array.**

*Here I have Tried to assign the value to arr pointer(That points to the base address); an address that we get from the input function, of the same array filled with elements now. We have passed the pointer to the array in input function as one argument, and the array dimensions as the other.*

*Majorly the problem faced here is about pointers and their application into arrays. But I am not able to figure out how I'll make the changes*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can pass a 2D array as a function argument.

```
char *input (char [][m]arr, int n, int m)
```

You would read/write values the way you are doing in your code. Keep in mind that this is a feature introduced in `C99` and won't compile with older compilers.

Another option is to pass it as a pointer:

```
char *input (char *arr, int n, int m)
```

Here you would read or write the array like so:

```
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    for(j=0; j<M; j++){
        *(arr + i * n + j) = 'a';
        /* OR you can also do this */
        arr[i *n + j] = 'a';
    }   
}
```

Multidimensional arrays in C are stored in memory row by row. So if you allocated a 3 x 2 array, you would have 3 rows, each having 2 columns. But the memory layout would be:

0, 1 => row1

2, 3 => row2

4, 5 => row3

Here, 0,1,2,3,4,5 are the contiguous indices of the array. In order to access the 2nd column of 3rd row , given a pointer `arr` to the base address of the array, you would have to find the address of the correct cell in the array.

We know that each row has 2 cells so in order to jump to the 3rd row we need to add the `row_id * number_of_cols_per_row` to the base pointer. So to get to 3rd row, we need to do `arr + 2 * 2`. Once we are in the correct row we need to add the column offset of the column we want to access. So here we want to access the second column, so we add 1.

`arr + 2 * 2 + 1`

But this will be the address of the second column of the third row. In order to write here we need to use the `*` operator:

```
*(arr + 2 * 2 + 1) = 'a';
```

This is exactly what we are doing in the loop.

As an aside, in your code you are calling `scanf` with `%d` format specifier, which is for integers. But you are storing the value in a char array. This can be a potential bug, correct thing is to use `%c` specifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a two-dimensional array masterpiece as an argument or a parameter, you can specify the size of all dimensions when defining the parameter group in the called function, or you can omit the size description of the first dimension, such as:

```
void Func(int array[3][10]);
void Func(int array[][10]);
```

Comment: But I want the user to input the dimensions of the array

Comment: @UtkarshShrivastava oh , you can use ‘char arr[N][M]’ directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int N, int M, char arr[N][M]){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(j=0; j<M; j++){
            scanf("%c", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int N, M;
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);
    char arr[N][M];
    input(N, M, arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even though the question's title says how to pass 2D array as argument to a function, the OP in the end says that he is confused about pointers and their application in arrays. So I don't think it helps him to understand pointer arithmetic in multidimensional arrays.